# Connection to MYSQL from visual c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but here goes......I have a website that was developed in PHP using MYSQL.  Now, I am wanting to write an application in Visual C# which accesses the MYSQL database, and returns data from that database to the application.  I attempted this, and received the error "(xx.xxx.xxx.xx) is not allowed to connect to this MYSQL server".  After some research, I found that there was a way to turn this off on the server by IP address.  However, this application would eventually be distributed to other people and PC's, so I don't think this is a permanent solution.  I think I could open the MYSQL database to the world, but I'm hoping for some way that I can connect to MYSQL and tell the server that I am coming from the hello world application only.  Does anyone know if this is possible from Visual C# and MYSQL, or know of a secure way to connect to a remote website MYSQL database using an application that can have a dynamic IP address?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to solve the configuration problem with your My SQL Server installation.  My SQL communities might be of help in that quest.  If this is a shared hosting you won't have very much luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It is through a hosting company, but it is a dedicated server.  I'll check around the MYSQL boards and see if I can find anything out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramhound is right in that you need to reconfigure your server if you want to do anything like this, but if you want to connect to the server directly from the client applications, your client would need to have the password for your Mysql which is not ideal..

Instead you should set up a webservice on your database server, and use that to sent/receive data to and from the clients.